# Android: Passing AppWidgetId to a Service

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

I got a Widget on my HomeScreen on which i add an click to a Button. I pass the widget id from the Widget to a Service, but when im reading the WidgetId at the Service it's always 3.

Widget:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);


        // prints the correct appWidgetId
        System.out.println(appWidgetId);


        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button01, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

The Service looks like this:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {

        int widgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);

        // 3 is always printend
        System.out.println(widgetId);

        // More stuff here

    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do will not work, AFAIK, without some trickery.

There can be only one outstanding `PendingIntent` per `Intent`. So, if you create two `Intents` that are equivalent (match on non-extra data), and you try to create two `PendingIntents`, you really wind up with a single `PendingIntent` in the end. Which `Intent` is used depends a bit on the flags you supply to `getService()` (or `getActivity()` or `getBroadcast()`). In your case, the first `Intent` will always be used.

If you only had one outstanding `PendingIntent` but just wanted to update its extras, `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` would work. But, you want N outstanding `PendingIntents`.

The only way I know of to make that work in your case is to put a unique action string in the `Intent`. Since you are specifying the component (`WidgetService.class`), the action string will not be used for routing. However, it will suffice to give you multiple `PendingIntent` objects.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the comment above, see this example for how to make your intent unique:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/StackWidget/src/com/example/android/stackwidget/StackWidgetProvider.html
It seems like a really dumb design and an even worse workaround, but I guess that's the way it is. It took me a long time to find the simple example above. Pay particular attention to the intent.setData(Uri) call. I cut and pasted those lines into my onUpdate() method and it finally worked.

Comment: Great find. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while, and all along it as in the base-line example. Geez. Thanks a bunch!